# Disable autocommit for SQL Server connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sql-developer

I am using Oracle's SQL Developer to execute queries against my SQL Server 2008 database as I simply can't work with SSMS as long as it doesn't support Ctrl + Return to execute statements...

Anyway, statements in SQL Server seem to be autocommit even when using Oracle SQL Developer. Is it possible to change this on a permanent basis? `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server uses autocommit mode by default. This cannot be changed permanently.

There are two ways implicit transactions (non-autocommit) can be turned on:

1. At the server level such that new sessions use it by default, using [`sp_configure 'user options'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763.aspx) -- this may or may not work depending on how SQL Developer was implemented.
2. For a session, using [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use this option in SQL Developer. When executing it, I get "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON"

Comment: @Daniel: See my edit. If neither of those work, I don't know what to suggest... if SQL Developer isn't passing that statement on to SQL Server, you're out of luck (use a different development tool).

Comment: The user options can even be configured via a dialog, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). "implicit transactions" is the first entry in the list. But it doesn't seem to make an difference, not in SQL Developer and not in SSMS... :(

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, the GUI uses `sp_configure` under the hood. As the linked document says, that option only works in very specific cases.

Comment: I don't really see these "specific cases" in the documentation. It just states that you don't have to restart the server and that it doesn't affect existing connections. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Daniel: "For dblib network library connections, controls whether a transaction is started implicitly when a statement is executed. **The IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS setting has no effect on ODBC or OLEDB connections**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Ah, skipped right over that one when reading. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry I couldn't find an out-of-the-box solution to this. I suppose it would be possible to write a macro or something for SSMS to do it.

Comment: For me the bigger problem that this isn't working in *any* way inside SQL developer...

Answer (score -6):

In SQL Developer you can try this technique:

```
/*sqldev:stmt*/begin transaction;
INSERT ...
update ...
/*sqldev:stmt*/rollback;
```

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826779/disable-autocommit-in-sql-developer-when-using-mysql

Comment: The OP clearly says: _'`BEGIN TRANSACTION` is not a solution for me.'_

Comment: Well, actually, SQL Developer is blocking everything starting with `BEGIN`. So, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` itself is not a solution for anybody. The magic comment does the trick. I was looking for the same in SQL Developer as the OP; I think this solution sould be mentioned here. It wasn't straiforward to find it.

Comment: SQL Developer is written in Java and typicaly uses JDBC Drivers for connection to databases. Answer given by Jon is not working for Daniel nor for me.